# Calling a dynamic function with variable arguments?

Tags: objective-c, macros, runtime, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to write myself a little macro to allow me to dynamically link and call a function that has variable arguments.  For example, the function I want to call has a method signature that looks like this:

```
extern void Foo(NSString *bar, NSString *format, ...);
```

I would like the invocation of my macro to look something like this:

```
 DYNAMIC_LINK_FUNCTION_WITH_VARGS(FooFramework, Foo, void, (NSString *bar, NSString *format), (option, format))
```

I have an existing macro that I'm trying to adapt to handle this:

```
#define DYNAMIC_LINK_FUNCTION(framework, functionName, resultType, parameterDeclarations, parameterNames)
```

Part of which does this:

```
functionName = (resultType (*) parameterDeclarations) dlsym(Load##framework(), #functionName); \
return functionName parameterNames; \
```

But I'm not sure where/how to incorporate the "..."

Here's the original macro in its complete form:

```
#define  DYNAMIC_LINK_FUNCTION(framework, functionName, resultType, parameterDeclarations, parameterNames) \
static resultType init##functionName parameterDeclarations; \
static resultType (*dynamicLink##functionName) parameterDeclarations = init##functionName; \
\
static resultType init##functionName parameterDeclarations \
{ \
dynamicLink##functionName = (resultType (*) parameterDeclarations) dlsym(Load##framework(), #functionName); \
return dynamicLink##functionName parameterNames; \
}
```

Comment: Show the complete original macro definition.

Comment: Edited original post

Comment: How is that related to Objective-C?

Comment: I realize what the macro is doing, but you cannot forward variable arguments, so you cannot use that particular function. You need to find the corresponding function that has a `va_list` parameter.

Comment: Ok, I was afraid of that.  Thanks

Comment: I'm in an Objective-C environment.  Maybe there's a higher level way to do this?

Comment: ObjC doesn't change the way plain functions are called. There's a _lower_ level way, though: you should be able to make this work if you're willing to mess around with [libffi](http://www.sourceware.org/libffi/).

Comment: Not sure if this will work in your case due to the extra level of abstraction, but could you use the ##__VA_ARGS__ variadic macro to accomplish it?  A simplified example:

    #define ConsoleDebug(s, ...) NSLog(@"DEBUG: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:s, ##__VA_ARGS__])

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html for much more detail.